# android webview not showing web page

Tags: xamarin

I am having difficulty displaying a web page in a webview in xamarin forms application.
I started out with eshoponcontainers sample application. which went well till I got to the login stage. When the Authorization request is sent the login page doesnt show up. A test in postman revealed an unathorised client error so I was expecting to see that page loaded in my webview but that is not happening. 
My .xaml page is as follows

```
<AbsoluteLayout
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsLogin}">
            <WebView     
              Source="{Binding LoginUrl}"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <WebView.Behaviors>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Behavior">
                        <On Platform="iOS, Android">
                            <On.Value>
                                <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior 
                                    EventName="Navigating"
                                    EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource WebNavigatingEventArgsConverter}"
                                    Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" />
                            </On.Value>
                        </On>
                        <On Platform="UWP">
                            <On.Value>
                                <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior 
                                    EventName="Navigated"
                                    EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource WebNavigatedEventArgsConverter}"
                                    Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" />
                            </On.Value>
                        </On>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </WebView.Behaviors>
            </WebView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

The code behind looks like this

```
public partial class LoginView : ContentPage
{
    private bool _animate;
    public LoginView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        var content = this.Content;
        this.Content = null;
        this.Content = content;

        var vm = BindingContext as LoginViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.InvalidateMock();

            if (!vm.IsMock)
            {
                _animate = true;
                await AnimateIn();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        _animate = false;
    }

    public async Task AnimateIn()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
        {
            return;
        }

        await AnimateItem(Banner, 10500);
    }

    private async Task AnimateItem(View uiElement, uint duration)
    {
        try
        {
            while (_animate)
            {
                await uiElement.ScaleTo(1.05, duration, Easing.SinInOut);
                await Task.WhenAll(
                    uiElement.FadeTo(1, duration, Easing.SinInOut),
                    uiElement.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(uiElement.Width, uiElement.Height))),
                    uiElement.FadeTo(.9, duration, Easing.SinInOut),
                    uiElement.ScaleTo(1.15, duration, Easing.SinInOut)
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following inthe "LoginViewModel"

```
 public class LoginViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private ValidatableObject<string> _userName;
    private ValidatableObject<string> _password;
    private bool _isMock;
    private bool _isValid;
    private bool _isLogin;
    private string _authUrl;

    private ISettingsService _settingsService;
    private IOpenUrlService _openUrlService;
    private IIdentityService _identityService;

    public LoginViewModel(
        ISettingsService settingsService,
        IOpenUrlService openUrlService,
        IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _settingsService = settingsService;
        _openUrlService = openUrlService;
        _identityService = identityService;

        _userName = new ValidatableObject<string>();
        _password = new ValidatableObject<string>();

        InvalidateMock();
        AddValidations();
    }

    public ValidatableObject<string> UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return _userName;
        }
        set
        {
            _userName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => UserName);
        }
    }

    public ValidatableObject<string> Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Password);
        }
    }

    public bool IsMock
    {
        get
        {
            return _isMock;
        }
        set
        {
            _isMock = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsMock);
        }
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return _isValid;
        }
        set
        {
            _isValid = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsValid);
        }
    }

    public bool IsLogin
    {
        get
        {
            return _isLogin;
        }
        set
        {
            _isLogin = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsLogin);
        }
    }

    public string LoginUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _authUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            _authUrl = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => LoginUrl);
        }
    }

    public ICommand MockSignInCommand => new Command(async () => await MockSignInAsync());

    public ICommand SignInCommand => new Command(async () => await SignInAsync());

    public ICommand RegisterCommand => new Command(Register);

    public ICommand NavigateCommand => new Command<string>(async (url) => await NavigateAsync(url));

    public ICommand SettingsCommand => new Command(async () => await SettingsAsync());

    public ICommand ValidateUserNameCommand => new Command(() => ValidateUserName());

    public ICommand ValidatePasswordCommand => new Command(() => ValidatePassword());

    public override Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
    {
        if (navigationData is LogoutParameter)
        {
            var logoutParameter = (LogoutParameter)navigationData;

            if (logoutParameter.Logout)
            {
                Logout();
            }
        }

        return base.InitializeAsync(navigationData);
    }

    private async Task MockSignInAsync()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        IsValid = true;
        bool isValid = Validate();
        bool isAuthenticated = false;

        if (isValid)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);

                isAuthenticated = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"[SignIn] Error signing in: {ex}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IsValid = false;
        }

        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            _settingsService.AuthAccessToken = GlobalSetting.Instance.AuthToken;

            await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<MainViewModel>();
            await NavigationService.RemoveLastFromBackStackAsync();
        }

        IsBusy = false;
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        await Task.Delay(10);

        LoginUrl = _identityService.CreateAuthorizationRequest();

        IsValid = true;
        IsLogin = true;
        IsBusy = false;
    }

    private void Register()
    {
        _openUrlService.OpenUrl(GlobalSetting.Instance.RegisterWebsite);
    }

    private void Logout()
    {
        var authIdToken = _settingsService.AuthIdToken;
        var logoutRequest = _identityService.CreateLogoutRequest(authIdToken);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logoutRequest))
        {
            // Logout
            LoginUrl = logoutRequest;
        }

        if (_settingsService.UseMocks)
        {
            _settingsService.AuthAccessToken = string.Empty;
            _settingsService.AuthIdToken = string.Empty;
        }

        _settingsService.UseFakeLocation = false;
    }

    private async Task NavigateAsync(string url)
    {
        var unescapedUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(url);

        if (unescapedUrl.Equals(GlobalSetting.Instance.LogoutCallback))
        {
            _settingsService.AuthAccessToken = string.Empty;
            _settingsService.AuthIdToken = string.Empty;
            IsLogin = false;
            LoginUrl = _identityService.CreateAuthorizationRequest();
        }
        else if (unescapedUrl.Contains(GlobalSetting.Instance.IdentityCallback))
        {
            var authResponse = new AuthorizeResponse(url);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authResponse.Code))
            {
                var userToken = await _identityService.GetTokenAsync(authResponse.Code);
                string accessToken = userToken.AccessToken;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
                {
                    _settingsService.AuthAccessToken = accessToken;
                    _settingsService.AuthIdToken = authResponse.IdentityToken;
                    await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<MainViewModel>();
                    await NavigationService.RemoveLastFromBackStackAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task SettingsAsync()
    {
        await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<SettingsViewModel>();
    }

    private bool Validate()
    {
        bool isValidUser = ValidateUserName();
        bool isValidPassword = ValidatePassword();

        return isValidUser && isValidPassword;
    }

    private bool ValidateUserName()
    {
        return _userName.Validate();
    }

    private bool ValidatePassword()
    {
        return _password.Validate();
    }

    private void AddValidations()
    {
        _userName.Validations.Add(new IsNotNullOrEmptyRule<string> { ValidationMessage = "A username is required." });
        _password.Validations.Add(new IsNotNullOrEmptyRule<string> { ValidationMessage = "A password is required." });
    }

    public void InvalidateMock()
    {
        IsMock = _settingsService.UseMocks;
    }
}
```

Comment: From postman are you getting markup returned or just a 401 status code?  If just the code then you're webview wont display anything.

Comment: I get an error page with the following details "Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client , Request Id: 0HLCK3GU9V5C7" this shows up when I try to get a new access token

Comment: Does your webview load any html content?  Like stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Yes, it does without any issues

Comment: if I run the authorization url directly in the browser I get the login page

Comment: Perhaps the authorized endpoint only allows certain clients/agents.  Perhaps you can customize your webview/requests to match the agent of your browser.